# SharePoint 2016 MUI Variation labels

Tags: variations, mui

I'm currently creating a multi language SharePoint site for our team at work.
As soon as I created my first variation labels, I got the following error.

> Sorry, something went wrong  An unexpected error has occurred. 
>   Technical Details
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-1026-c482-xxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Date and Time: 2019-02-22 15:53:45

I found this reference on the web [ragavj.blogspot](http://ragavj.blogspot.com/2016/12/tried-creating-new-variation-label.html) but it didn't change anything.

Anyone can help figure out how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint was unable to create label variation subsites because the main site language was set to French. It was searching for column headers name that didn't match the actual column headers.
We created a copy of the SharePoint site in English and didn't have the issue anymore.